# How to generate linked-axis in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to create a plot with linked x-axis s.t. top and bottom tick/labels are measurement of units (Joules and kJoules). I've seen examples with sharex etc but my needs are following:

1. How to make the axis linked where tickmark/labels on second are generated from first axis
2. When change limits on one axis, the other should automatically update

The easiest thing (not at all elegant) would be to create two x-variables:

```
x1 = np.arange(0,10000,1000)
x2 = x1/1000.
y = np.random.randint(0,10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x1, y, 'ro')

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.plot(x2,y,visible=False)
plt.show()
```

This produces the following:

[image: okay]

But things break when I attempt to set the x-axis limits on either. E.g., doing `ax2.set_xlim(2,5)` only changes the axis on top.

[image: noo, thats not what I want]

Since I already know that x1 and x2 are related, how should I set up the plot so that when I change one, the other is automatically taken care of.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to use a parasite axes with a specified scale. There is an [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/parasite_simple2.html) of this on the matlpotlib site, slightly modified version is below.

```
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.parasite_axes import SubplotHost
import numpy as np

# Set seed for random numbers generator to make data recreateable
np.random.seed(1235) 

# Define data to be plotted
x1 = np.arange(0,10000,1000)
x2 = x1/1000.
y1 = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
y2 = y1/5.

# Create figure instance
fig = plt.figure()

# Make AxesHostAxesSubplot instance
ax = SubplotHost(fig, 1, 1, 1)

# Scale for top (parasite) x-axis: makes top x-axis 1/1000 of bottom x-axis
x_scale = 1000.
y_scale = 1.

# Set scales of parasite axes to x_scale and y_scale (relative to ax)
aux_trans = mtransforms.Affine2D().scale(x_scale, y_scale)

# Create parasite axes instance
ax_parasite = ax.twin(aux_trans) 
ax_parasite.set_viewlim_mode('transform')

fig.add_subplot(ax)

# Plot the data
ax.plot(x1, y1)
ax_parasite.plot(x2, y2)

# Configure axis labels and ticklabels
ax.set_xlabel('Original x-axis')
ax_parasite.set_xlabel('Parasite x-axis (scaled)')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax_parasite.axis['right'].major_ticklabels.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

This gives the output below

[image]

If you change the limits of the `ax` instance, the limits of the `ax_parasite` instance are updated automatically:

```
# Set limits of original axis (parasite axis are scaled automatically)
ax.set_ylim(0,12)
ax.set_xlim(500,4000)
```

[image]