# matplotlib: left yaxis and right yaxis to have different units

Tags: matplotlib, axis

I'm plotting curves in Kelvin.
I would like to have the left yaxis to show units in Kelvin and the right yaxis to show them in Celsius, and both rounded to the closest integer (so the ticks are not aligned, as TempK=TempC+273.15)

```
fig=plt.figure
figure=fig.add_subplot(111)
figure.plot(xpos, tos, color='blue')
```

I should not use `twinx()` as it allows superimposing curves with two different scales, which is not my case (only the right axis has to be changed, not the curves).

Comment: You need to use `twinx()` to do this, since by definition you are using two different scales. Use `set_xticklabels()` to define the labels you want.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, actually I realised that after posting, and eventually came to a solution (see below).

Comment: This post to the mailing list might be helpful; http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=012701ce5892%24683e5cb0%2438bb1610%24%40earthlink.net&forum_name=matplotlib-devel

Comment: Seeing as how in this case one should be able to read values from a curve on both y-axes, I'd make use of `ParasiteAxes` and a `Affine2D().translate()` transformation, especially if it is meant for interactive use (panning/zooming). This makes it possible for the parasite y-axis to have an offset from (or being a scale of) the primary y-axis. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16993109/2022086) an earlier answer of mine using parasite axes.

Comment: Yes, this solution looks appropriate: I'll think about that next time I need a linked-axis. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]I found the following solution:

```
fig=plt.figure
figure=fig.add_subplot(111)
figure.plot(xpos, tos, color='blue')
... plot other curves if necessary
... and once all data are plot, one can create a new axis

y1, y2=figure.get_ylim()
x1, x2=figure.get_xlim()
ax2=figure.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(y1-273.15, y2-273.15)
ax2.set_yticks( range(int(y1-273.15), int(y2-273.15), 2) )
ax2.set_ylabel('Celsius')
ax2.set_xlim(x1, x2)
figure.set_ylabel('Surface Temperature (K)')
```

Do not forget to set the twinx axis xaxis!

Comment: Your `figure`variable is in fact not the figure at all but the axes, confusing.